# Move out and centered one div from inline-block divs group with float left alignment

Tags: html, css

I have 5 divs aligned with float left and inline-block. I want move out one div of they and centered in the middle of the page.

I try to reset the float and set the position absolute, but the div doesn't centered (still in the right at page).

If reset the position (relative) the div is centered correctly, but the others divs move to the bottom of the page (i don't understand why).

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
background-color: #00ced1;
}

/* Box */
.box {
background-color: #ff0000;
border: .250rem solid #fff;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
float: left;
font-family: segoe ui;
margin: 1.5% 1%;
padding: 1rem;
text-align: center;
transition: position .35s ease-in,
margin .35s ease-in,
width .35s ease-in,
transform .35s ease-in;
}

.box:hover {
background-color: #20b2aa;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
display: block;
float: none;
position: relative;
width: calc(100/4- 2*1rem - 2*1% - 2*.250rem);
margin: 200px auto;
}

/* Width of the boxes */
.width {
width: calc(100%/4 - 2*1rem - 2*1% - 2*.250rem);
}
```

Here is the example at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/035j1s90/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you want to center one `<div>` in the middle and place the other four `<div>`'s directly underneath it. The large gap between the centered div and the four div's is because of the `margin: 200px auto` property which you've specified inside the CSS for `.box:nth-child(1)`. Simply change it to `margin: 0px auto 0px auto` and your layout will be fine then, like this:

---

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #00ced1;
}

/* Box */
.box {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border: .250rem solid #fff;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: segoe ui;
  margin: 1.5% 1%;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  transition: position .35s ease-in,
    margin .35s ease-in,
    width .35s ease-in,
    transform .35s ease-in;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #20b2aa;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100/4- 2*1rem - 2*1% - 2*.250rem);
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
/* Width of the boxes */
.width {
  width: calc(100%/4 - 2*1rem - 2*1% - 2*.250rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="box width">Translate</div>
<div class="box width">Rotate</div>
<div class="box width">Scale</div>
<div class="box width">Skew</div>
<div class="box width">Matrix</div>
```

**UPDATED:**

I've modified your HTML structure just a little bit. `<div class="box width">Translate</div>` which you want to be centered has been moved in the end of your HTML and I've put it inside `<div id="centered"><div>`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #00ced1;
}
/* Box */

.box {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border: .250rem solid #fff;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: segoe ui;
  margin: 1.5% 1%;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  transition: position .35s ease-in, margin .35s ease-in, width .35s ease-in, transform .35s ease-in;
}
.box:hover {
  background-color: #20b2aa;
}
#centered {
  text-align: center;
}
#centered .box {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
/* Width of the boxes */

.width {
  width: calc(100%/4 - 2*1rem - 2*1% - 2*.250rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="box width">Rotate</div>
<div class="box width">Scale</div>
<div class="box width">Skew</div>
<div class="box width">Matrix</div>
<div id="centered">
  <div class="box width">Translate</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want the div 'Translate' centered but the others div still in the top. If a try to down the div the others divs will go to bottom.

Comment: Can I modify your HTML structure to achieve what you're trying to do or the HTML has to remain the same?